# typescript unable to resolve type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, log4javascript

I am trying to use log4javascript in a project and I see that the package does have log4javascript.d.ts present in node_modules/log4javascript/ and the package.json does refer to it in the "typings" property but when compiling my project it complains with:

> S2307: Cannot find module 'log4javascript'

I am importing the module using:

```
import {getLogger } from 'log4javascript';
```

From what I understand one does not need to install typings separately with:

> npm install @types/log4javascript

as the typing is already present. But I am not sure how do I use the module types and methods if I have:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

set in my tsconfig.json

My tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "include": [
        "static/js/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify in your `tsconfig.json`  the `"moduleResolution": "node"` option

If you specify `target: "es2015"` then the module system will be `es2015`. If the module system is `es2015` then the resolution for modules defaults to `clasic` which does not look in `node_modules` for types (as stated [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)). You can find this in the docs for the compiler [options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering when do you use what module system? I am building a project which is to be run in a browser supporting es2015.

Comment: @Divick at the moment I'm working on an Angular project and I just use what `ng create` set up for me, which is `"module": "es2015"` with `"moduleResolution": "node"`